# Is it possible to create a multi dimensional array with varying types?

Tags: vb.net, object, multidimensional-array

I have 3 controls that consists of a label, a listbox and a textbox on the same line. On a different line I have 3 different controls of the same type which is label, a listbox and a textbox. I want to put them into a 3 dimensional array like this:

```
Dim multiArray() As Object = { {Lane1Label, ListBox1, TextBox1}, 
    {Lane2Label, ListBox2, TextBox2} }
```

But it's not letting me do this. Is there a way?

Comment: Sure, create a class to hold the controls and then put them in a list...

Comment: I would recommend you use a `DataTable` instead

Comment: Note that in the code you posted, you are declaring a 1-dimensional array, and trying to assign a 2-dimensional array to it. To declare a 2-dimensional array, use `Dim multiArray(,) As Object`. Or as these are all controls, it might be better to use `Dim multiArray(,) As Control`

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Make a class (maybe even a custom or user control) to contain each line of controls:

```
Public Class ControlLine
    Public Property Lane As Label
    Public Property List As ListBox
    Public Property Text As TextBox
End Class
```

Then create a single dimensional array of these objects (or usually even better: a `List(Of ControlLine)` ) and put your items in here:

```
Dim lines() As ControlLine = { 
   New ControlLine With { Lane = LaneLabel1, List = ListBox1, Text = TextBox1},
   New ControlLine With { Lane = LaneLabel2, List = ListBox2, Text = TextBox2}
}
```

This is *much better* because the items in your array remain strongly-typed, for good compile-time checking and IDE support for things like intellisense. Recent versions of Visual Studio can also accomplish this via Tuples.

And again, also consider abstracting this further into custom or user controls, where you can create a whole set with one simple constructor call, place one control on the form and have the whole set line up properly, and even think about **data binding** these ControlLines to a container like a `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of managing all the controls and arrays and placement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Dim multiArray(,) As Object = _
{ _
    {Lane1Label, ListBox1, TextBox1}, _
    {Lane2Label, ListBox2, TextBox2} _
}
```

Note the `,` in the declaration of the two-dimensional array.

Comment: I would love to know why the down-votes - this directly answers the question.

Comment: Because it's bad coding practice. You could end up with any type of object in any of the elements. You should use strong typing to define what types of object can be stored.

Comment: Sorry, but as much experience as you have, I dont mean to "teach grandma how to suck eggs" :)

Comment: @DavidWilson - Yes, I agree, but this question asked something very specific and I felt it was worth answering it directly.